# SQL If cell is blank, look at adjacent cell for value, search that column for match, and fill blank cell with corresponding value

Tags: sql

No sure if this is possible, but here's what I'm trying to do. I have a table like this:

```
URL         | URL_NAME
www.foo.com | ad_Blue_Heron_Resort
www.foo.com |
```

I will always have two URL rows, but only one URL NAME. I'd like to fill the blanks with the corresponding URL NAME. Given the above, is it possible to have a query that searches for blanks, when it finds a blank, looksup the adjacent URL "www.foo.com" then searchs the URL column for a match, then copies the URL NAME into the blank cell?

I'm thinking something like this, but I just can't wrap my head around it:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN URL_NAME IS NULL
  search URL column for a match for www.foo.com, and get URL_NAME from that row
END as URL_NAME
```

Obviously that's not real SQL, but I don't know what function I can use for this...

UPDATE I'm using Marketing Cloud SQL, so not all features of TSQL are available. This is what I have so far and it seems like it should work, but it isn't. It's based on the first answer posted.

```
select LinkContent, CASE WHEN (LinkName = '' OR LinkName IS NULL) THEN
(SELECT max(LinkName) from [Link Ranking] n2 where n2.LinkContent = n.LinkContent)
END as LinkName
FROM [Link Ranking] n
```

I can't seem to alias a table twice either...

**UPDATE**
Ok this ended up working for me, but it also gave me too many results, so that's something else I'll need to investigate

```
SELECT n.LinkContent,
CASE WHEN LEN(n.LinkName)>0 THEN
    n.LinkName
ELSE
    n2.LinkName
END as LinkName
FROM [Newsletter Link Ranking Past month] n with (NOLOCK)
JOIN (
    SELECT LinkContent, LinkName
    FROM [Newsletter Link Ranking Past month] with (NOLOCK)
    WHERE LinkName IS NOT NULL
) n2 
ON n.LinkContent = n2.LinkContent
```

Comment: There is no such thing as an "adjacent" row.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.

Comment: What's your DBMS, does it support `LAST_VALUE`? If it also supports the `IGNORE NULLS` option it's simple. If there's always only a single URL_NAME perURL then Gordon's answer is fine.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry that's just bad choice of words. Not necessarily adjacent cell, but find the corresponding cell in the URL column and match it. I'm using Microsoft SQL

Comment: Yes @dnoeth there will only ever be a single URL_NAME per URL

Comment: Why do you even need the "duplicate" rows with "blanks"?

Comment: @shawnt00 because there are other rows with counts that I need, just not showing here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a set-based way to do this. I make the following assumptions:

- For each distinct value in column URL, the values in URL_Name will either be the same identical value or NULL
- "No value" means NULL.  If not, check the comments below for if you need to check for empty strings.

Code:

```
--  Based on the assumptions, this gets the URL_Name for each URL
SELECT URL, max(URL_Name)
 from MyTable
 where URL_Name is not null  --  or, where URL_Name <> ''


--  Next make that a CTE--essentially, a temporary table that can be referenced
--  in the subsequent statement
WITH cteNames as
 (
    SELECT URL, max(URL_Name)  URL_Name
     from MyTable
     where URL_Name is not null  --  or, where URL_Name <> ''
 )
UPDATE MyTable
 set URL_Name = cte.URL_Name
 from MyTable mt
  inner join cteNames cte
   on cte.URL = mt.URL
 where mt.URL_Name is null  --  or, where URL_Name = ''
```

(Caveat: I did not test this code against a table, so some tweaking might be required.)

--  Edit  --------------

```
--  Here's the same written using subqueries
UPDATE MyTable
 set URL_Name = maxURL.URL_Name
 from MyTable mt
  inner join (
              select URL, max(URL_Name)  URL_Name
               from MyTable
               where URL_Name is not null  --  or, where URL_Name <> ''
             )  maxURL
   on maxURL.URL = mt.URL
 where mt.URL_Name is null  --  or, where URL_Name = ''
```

Comment: I should have mentioned I'm using Marketing Cloud sql which doesn't allow all functions of T-SQL

Comment: This could be done with subqueries, or even storing results from a first query in a temp table for a second query. I used the CTE because they tend to be a bit easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can fill the blanks in a query using window functions:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(url, max(url_name) over (partition by url)) as new_url_name
from t;
```

In an update, you can do this.  One method that will work in any database is:

```
update t
    set url_name = (select max(url_name) from t t2 where t2.url = t.url)
    where url_name is null;
```

Comment: So the only problem with the first one is that I need to fill the blank cell in URL_NAME, not a third column. Is that possible? Or maybe you were suggesting I have another table and run that first query on the second table?

Comment: @garek007: Use `max(url_name) over (partition by url)` *instead* of `url_name`

Comment: Ok thanks @dnoeth I think I can actually adapt the second one to work for me, but how are you able to use two tables without a second from? t and t2 are both tables am I right?

Comment: @garek007: `t` and `t2` are the same table, just two different *aliases*.

Comment: hmm the first one validates and runs ok, but it's just duplicating the URL column. I'm still working on trying to get the second working

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick

```
SELECT n.LinkContent,
    CASE WHEN LEN(n.LinkName)>0 THEN
        n.LinkName
    ELSE
        n2.LinkName
    END as LinkName
    FROM [Newsletter Link Ranking Past month] n with (NOLOCK)
    JOIN (
        SELECT LinkContent, LinkName
        FROM [Newsletter Link Ranking Past month] with (NOLOCK)
        WHERE LinkName IS NOT NULL
    ) n2 
    ON n.LinkContent = n2.LinkContent
```